# Alternative remote desktop to Teamviewer for multiple monitor setup

Tags: remote-desktop

My work computer has 3 screens. My work laptop has 3 screens. I love how Teamviewer lets me open a separate window for each monitor. I then move those tabs to each screen and it's exactly like I'm at my host computer, seeing all 3 screens at once. Is there another free remote desktop program that operates like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zoho Assist](https://www.zoho.com/assist/) it allows you to use multiple monitors and free.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way with Google Remote Desktop. You can open 3 chrome remote desktops on your computer and open 3 sessions, one to each screen. But you have to use different ways/options to access, otherwise you may get disconnected because the option “Remote access” disconnect the first session if you open another one.

So, here's how to:
One session you connect to the host using the option “remote access” and the other two you connect using the option “remote support” (this is the one you have to generate a code).

After connected, at the options shown when you click in the arrow at the right corner, select one screen to each session and change all of them to full-screen.

A bit boring doing all these steps, but after done it works well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1217972)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @DaveM, I've just fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Connectwise Control might be useful if you are trying to remote access into different computers.

Comment: nope. want same computer. 3 windows on same computer.